# Partial Views not using parents Resources?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been working on a MVC 4 web app. I'm injecting a partial view into my index view, but no Resources that have been rendered in my layout page are being used by my partial view.  For example, I can not use any jquery functions on any element inside the partial. So is there anything that could be causing this issue?

I've actually done it 2 ways: through razor and through jquery. I want to use jquery, but it wont work with it after its been rendered.

```
<script>
        $("#Display div").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).first().find("input").attr("value");
            $.ajax({                
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/GetActors")',
                    data: {id:id},
                    success: function (result)
                    {
                        $('#Display').html(result);
                    }
                });
        });
</script>                                        

`@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "GetActors", new { id = actor.ActorId }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "Display", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })`


        public PartialViewResult GetActors(int id)
    {
        return PartialView("GetActors",Db.Actors.Find(id));
    }
```

**Layout View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-rating.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body style="background:url(http://res.cloudinary.com/arcangel210291/image/upload/v1416947586/1389017_do9nat.jpg) no-repeat fixed; background-size:cover;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" style="border-radius:0px;">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a><span style="color:#B99A77" class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span></a></li>
                <li><a>Movies</a></li>
                <li><a>Actors</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">

                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btnMovies" data-toggle="dropdown">ALL<span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a>Somthing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />

                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btnMovies"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container glass" id="NavContainer">
    @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/starrating");
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Index**

```
@model IEnumerable<S00133799_CA2.Models.MovieModels.Movie>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse container" id="userControls">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li role="presentation">@Ajax.ActionLink("Create New!", "","", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "Display", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btnMovies" })</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li role="presentation" ><p class="navbar-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Sort By : </p></li>
            <li role="presentation">@Ajax.ActionLink("Name △", "OrderBy", new { OrderType = "Name" }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "Display", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btnMovies" })</li>
            <li role="presentation">@Ajax.ActionLink("Date △", "OrderBy", new { OrderType = "Date" }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId="Display", InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btnMovies" })</li>
            <li role="presentation">@Ajax.ActionLink("Rating △", "OrderBy",new { OrderType = "Rating" }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId="Display", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btnMovies" })</li>
            <li role="presentation">@Ajax.ActionLink("All Movies", "OrderBy", new { OrderType = "ChangeToMovies" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "Display", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btnMovies" })</li>
            <li role="presentation">@Ajax.ActionLink("All Actors", "OrderBy", new { OrderType = "ChangeToActors" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "Display", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btnMovies" })</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="Display" class="row">
        @foreach (var movie in Model)
        {
           <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-4'>
                <div class='thumbnail' style="cursor:pointer">
                    <img src="@movie.MovieImage" class="img-responsive" style="height:310px; width:100%" alt='...'/>
                    <div class='caption text-center panel panel-warning' style='margin-bottom:3%;padding:0;'>
                        <h4 style='background: #B99A77;color: #ffffff;margin-top: 0;padding: 2%;border-radius: 2px;'>@Html.DisplayFor(modle=>movie.MovieName)</h4>
                        <h5><b class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(model=> movie.ReleaseDate)</b></h5>
                        <input type="hidden" value="@movie.MovieId" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }       
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse container" id="footernav">
        <ul class="pager">
            @if((int)Session["PageNo"] != 0)
            {<li class="disabled"><a>Previous</a></li>}
            else{
                <li> @Ajax.ActionLink("Previous", "Previous", "", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="GET", UpdateTargetId="Display", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace })</li>
                }
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Next", "Next", "", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="GET", UpdateTargetId="Display", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace })</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Display div").on("click",function () {
                var id = $(this).first().find("input").attr("value");
                $.ajax({                
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/GetMovies")',
                    data: {id:id},
                    success: function (result)
                    {
                        $("#userControls").hide();
                        $("#footernav").hide();
                        $('#Display').html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: can you show us some code, for example how you are injecting the partialview and partialview code

Comment: and after you did that, you jquery selectors are not working?

Comment: After my i load the partial page and insert it into my div i can't use Jquery to select anything. no scripts are being used by the partial at all i have a rating plugin that works outside my partial but not inside it.

Comment: You have not included enough code to be sure, but you need to use event delegation (jquery `.on()`) for dynamically added elements. And make sure you scripts are at the bottom of the page or wrapped in document.ready

Answer (score 0):

Seams that you have is because you html is rendered on the page dynamically using ajax request after your selectors are assigned, you have 2 options:
1- reload your js files or code again after injecting your partial view.
2- use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or live for older jquery versions on your selectors and events (I recommend this if possible).

Comment: Tried both of these, the scripts are being handled by the script bundler. The problem only occurs when the partial has been injected

Comment: do you get any js errors when you inject your partial view? you can check using firebug or chrome dev tools

Comment: All's clean ive been using chrome debuger but nothing

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I actually Did somthing realy stupid. I placed the scripts into the partial itself to load them again like Amr has said i had done this before but left out one script that threw the whole thing. Thanks for the help anyway guys. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it went away when I added a reference to the path where the Resources files (*.resx) were located.

**MyPartialView.cshtml:**

```
@using MyApp.Infrastructure.Localization  <!-- This line solved my problem -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 align-center">
        <h2>@Language_Resources.String_Start_Your_App</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```